# Training Tensorflow2 model : Failed to find any matching files for checkpoint ( Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor )

Tags: neural-network, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, python-3.7

I am trying to train a custom Object Detection model with Tensorflow2 on Colab using [SSD mobileNet](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz).

I am following this tutorial step by step
https://medium.com/swlh/guide-to-tensorflow-object-detection-tensorflow-2-e55ba3cdbc03.

Python v3.7

Colabs link : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1N_zF5jOUT00OH1BRRs_A9kdippzAS7IQ?usp=sharing

```
!python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir="models/my_mobilenet" --pipeline_config_path="pre-trained-models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/pipeline.config"
```

After executing the command, below is the output.

```
2021-03-13 08:45:02.448113: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-03-13 08:45:04.757023: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-03-13 08:45:04.757846: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-03-13 08:45:04.787026: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-13 08:45:04.787608: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla T4 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 14.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 298.08GiB/s
2021-03-13 08:45:04.787645: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-03-13 08:45:04.790135: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-03-13 08:45:04.790228: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-03-13 08:45:04.791997: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-03-13 08:45:04.792359: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-03-13 08:45:04.794051: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-03-13 08:45:04.794750: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2021-03-13 08:45:04.794931: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-03-13 08:45:04.795055: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-13 08:45:04.795642: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-13 08:45:04.796163: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-03-13 08:45:04.796637: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-03-13 08:45:04.796760: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-13 08:45:04.797292: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla T4 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 14.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 298.08GiB/s
2021-03-13 08:45:04.797320: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-03-13 08:45:04.797358: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-03-13 08:45:04.797380: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-03-13 08:45:04.797402: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-03-13 08:45:04.797432: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-03-13 08:45:04.797455: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-03-13 08:45:04.797474: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2021-03-13 08:45:04.797494: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-03-13 08:45:04.797562: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-13 08:45:04.798123: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-13 08:45:04.798619: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-03-13 08:45:04.798662: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-03-13 08:45:05.293580: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-03-13 08:45:05.293642: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-03-13 08:45:05.293659: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-03-13 08:45:05.293876: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-13 08:45:05.294563: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-13 08:45:05.295158: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-13 08:45:05.295688: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:39] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
2021-03-13 08:45:05.295736: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 13994 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla T4, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 7.5)
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
I0313 08:45:05.297411 139933877315456 mirrored_strategy.py:350] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
I0313 08:45:05.301771 139933877315456 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I0313 08:45:05.301958 139933877315456 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0313 08:45:05.434074 139933877315456 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0313 08:45:05.435147 139933877315456 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0313 08:45:05.436801 139933877315456 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0313 08:45:05.437565 139933877315456 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0313 08:45:05.480596 139933877315456 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0313 08:45:05.483359 139933877315456 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0313 08:45:05.498590 139933877315456 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0313 08:45:05.499372 139933877315456 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0313 08:45:05.500731 139933877315456 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0313 08:45:05.501469 139933877315456 cross_device_ops.py:565] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
2021-03-13 08:45:06.823548: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-03-13 08:45:08.630254: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-03-13 08:45:09.109623: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/models/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:540: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
W0313 08:45:09.646384 139933877315456 deprecation.py:339] From /content/models/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:540: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted datasets: ['/content/annotations/train.tfrecord']
I0313 08:45:09.650547 139933877315456 dataset_builder.py:163] Reading unweighted datasets: ['/content/annotations/train.tfrecord']
INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file: ['/content/annotations/train.tfrecord']
I0313 08:45:09.650742 139933877315456 dataset_builder.py:80] Reading record datasets for input file: ['/content/annotations/train.tfrecord']
INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 1
I0313 08:45:09.650826 139933877315456 dataset_builder.py:81] Number of filenames to read: 1
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W0313 08:45:09.650906 139933877315456 dataset_builder.py:88] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:105: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
W0313 08:45:09.652242 139933877315456 deprecation.py:339] From /content/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:105: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:237: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
W0313 08:45:09.668024 139933877315456 deprecation.py:339] From /content/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:237: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
W0313 08:45:16.049755 139933877315456 deprecation.py:339] From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
W0313 08:45:18.964591 139933877315456 deprecation.py:339] From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/models/research/object_detection/inputs.py:282: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W0313 08:45:20.472738 139933877315456 deprecation.py:339] From /content/models/research/object_detection/inputs.py:282: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/py_checkpoint_reader.py", line 95, in NewCheckpointReader
    return CheckpointReader(compat.as_bytes(filepattern))
RuntimeError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for /content/pre-trained-model/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 113, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 110, in main
    record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 585, in train_loop
    unpad_groundtruth_tensors)
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 347, in load_fine_tune_checkpoint
    if not is_object_based_checkpoint(checkpoint_path):
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 310, in is_object_based_checkpoint
    var_names = [var[0] for var in tf.train.list_variables(checkpoint_path)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_utils.py", line 112, in list_variables
    reader = load_checkpoint(ckpt_dir_or_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_utils.py", line 67, in load_checkpoint
    return py_checkpoint_reader.NewCheckpointReader(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/py_checkpoint_reader.py", line 99, in NewCheckpointReader
    error_translator(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/py_checkpoint_reader.py", line 35, in error_translator
    raise errors_impl.NotFoundError(None, None, error_message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for /content/pre-trained-model/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0
```

Can someone explain why it is failed to find matching ckpt-0 from SSD mobileNet ?

I have another question what is TFrecord in tensorflow ?

Comment: Please post your relevant code *here*, not in an external repo; see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Plus, avoid asking several (irrelevant) questions at once.

Comment: please explain how can i edit the question ?

Answer (score 0):

i have similar error

> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/py_checkpoint_reader.py", line 35, in error_translator
> raise errors_impl.NotFoundError(None, None, error_message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful
> TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for
> efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32/checkpoint/ckpt-0

i am using a pretrained model and in config file of the model i replaced

```
train_config: {
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
```

by

```
train_config: {
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "./efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
```

and its working fine now

and your another answer to question  of tf record is,
TFRecord format, a simple format for storing a sequence of binary records.I recommend to visit

> [https://gilberttanner.com/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-with-tensorflow-2-creating-a-custom-model](http://%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://gilberttanner.com/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-with-tensorflow-2-creating-a-custom-model)

for better understanding and tutorial

Comment: tons of people say something similar in order to solve this problem, but in my case doesn't work. Another thing that is not clear to me is the fact that this problem was solved years ago by tf devs

Comment: Do you have same problem now ? or is it solved?

Comment: yes, i can't figure out how to fix this. As a work around i'm using tensorflow 1.15

Comment: How can I fix this error? `FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for /home/UbuntuUser/Desktop/Tensorflow_Object_Detection_with_Tensorflow_2/variables/variables
 You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device. Consider setting the `experimental_io_device` option in `tf.saved_model.LoadOptions` to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'.`